# Use a specific subdomain with ZNC

Tags: linux, networking, dns, fedora, irc

I recently installed ZNC on a Fedora 22 VPS I'm renting for educational purposes to try to strengthen my Linux skills and knowledge. One thing I am trying to do is set up a small IRC bouncer on this VPS using ZNC. I want to use a specific subdomain for all of the ZNC-related parts of my server, but after reading through the [documentation](http://wiki.znc.in/Configuration), I am still confused about how I would go about binding ZNC to a specific subdomain as compared to the root domain of the server (i.e. znc.example.com versus example.com).

How would I go about doing this? I feel like the BindHosts option is related, but I am having difficulty understanding its purpose.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, the BindHost option is used.** (The term "bind" comes from the Berkeley sockets API, which programs use to establish network connections. When a program wants to use a specific address, whether for connecting or for accepting connections, it uses the `bind(…)` function.)

Which leads to an important thing:

- Programs don't connect nor bind to domain names; they only use **IP addresses** for this.

  The actual domain name is only sent after establishing the connection with the service.

  (For example, web browsers send a "Host:" header as part of the HTTP request. But SSH clients don't send the domain name *at all*. Neither do IRC clients, generally.)

---

**So the answer is:**

First you need need to get a second IP address for your server, then tell ZNC – using the BindHost option – to bind to that new address (instead of "all"), and finally point your `znc` subdomain to that new address.

Be careful to use the right option, though – ZNC has two separate "bind host" options, one for accepting incoming connections (from you), and one for establishing outgoing connections (to the IRC servers).

And yes, you might see people using a domain name with BindHost. It is just a convenience trick, however – ZNC will merely translate the given name to an address, and will still bind only to that IP address, not to the name.

---

**Several years in the future,** there might be another answer:

Even though neither TCP nor IRC know about "domain names", they're often used with another protocol which does – TLS, aka SSL.

When using HTTPS (HTTP/TLS), all modern web browsers send the domain name over TLS as well, in the "server name indication" field, so the web server can decide much earlier.

Being part of TLS, this is not limited to HTTPS – I've already seen email clients & servers using SNI. Some IRC clients, such as Irssi, have added SNI support as well. There also are programs such as `stunnel` which can route connections on the same TCP port to various different programs based on the SNI domain name.

This means that in the near future you *will* be able to "bind" ZNC to only a single domain name, without needing a new IP address. But only after *all* of your IRC clients gain TLS SNI support.